Global asymptotic stability for difference equations
I tried to ask this question to the economics forum but no one was able to answer me. It regards the global asymptotic stability of the Solow model. But, I'll make the question as plain as possible without any reference to economics.
Consider the following difference equation:
\begin{equation}
k_{t+1} \equiv g(k_t) = s f(k_t) + (1-\delta)k_t
\end{equation}
where $s$ and $\delta$ are two constants, and $s \in (0,1)$, and $\delta \in (0,1)$. Further, $f : R_+ \to R_+$ and it is assumed to be such that $f'(k) >0$ and $f''(k)<0$, and $f'(0)=\infty$ and $f'(\infty)=0$.
The slides say that a sufficient condition for global asymptotic stability is that $|g'(k)| <1$ for all $k_t >0$ as $t \to \infty$. Then, with $k^{\ast}$ denoting the steady state value of $k_t$,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
|k_{t+1} - k^{\ast}| &= |g(k) - g(k^{\ast})| \\
&= \left| \int_{k^{\ast}}^{k_t} g'(k) \, dk \right| \\
&\leq \int_{k^{\ast}}^{k_t} |g'(k)| \, dk < |k_t - k^{\ast}|
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where the last inequality uses the stated assumption. Then the slides say: <<but this assumption is not true for our function $g(k):  g'(k) = sf'(k) + (1 - \delta) \to \infty$ as $ k \searrow 0$>>.
Due to the assumption that $f'(0) \infty$ it makes sense to me that $g'(k) = \to \infty$ as $ k \searrow 0$. The first question is (I'm sure I'm missing something very basic), why $\left| \int_{k^{\ast}}^{k_t} g'(k) \, dk \right| \leq \int_{k^{\ast}}^{k_t} |g'(k)| \, dk$ and why $\int_{k^{\ast}}^{k_t} |g'(k)| \, dk < |k_t - k^{\ast}|$
The slide then continue by saying: Suppose that $ k_t \in (0,k^{\ast})$:
\begin{equation}
k_{t+1} - k^{\ast} = g(k_t) - g(k^{\ast}) = - \int_{k^{\ast}}^{k_t} g'(k) dk <0
\end{equation}
since $ g'(k) > 1 - \delta > 0 $ for all $ k $, which implies that $ k_{t+1} \in (k_t, k^*) $ and, by induction over $ t $, that the level of capital at any time after $ t $ is bounded above by $ k $.
Here, It seems a kind of trivial self-imposed thing. Am I wrong?
Moreover, the slides ends as follows
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{k_{t+1} - k_t}{k_t} &= s \frac{f(k_t)}{k_t} - \delta \\
&> s \frac{f(k)}{k} - \delta \\
&= 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where the second line uses the concavity of $ f $ (which implies that $ f(k)=k $ is decreasing with $ k $) and the last line uses the definition of the steady-state value. Therefore, capital is monotonically approaching its steady-state level. We have shown that $ \{k_t\} $ is a monotonically increasing sequence.
What does not entirely convince me is what prevents $k_{t+1}$ to oscillate to the right of $k_{\ast}$ when $k_t \in (0, k^{\ast})$?
